# Error sending mail which states my IP has been blacklisted

Tags: c#, .net, email, system.net.mail

I am continously sending mails from different addresses, and I haven't had any problems so far.

Now I am sending a new mail (just ONE email), and in the `client.Send(message)` line it throws an exception;

```
{System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: El buzón de correo no está disponible. La respuesta del servidor fue: 5.7.1 Mail refused, your IP is blacklisted - See http://www.spamhaus.org/query/bl?ip=+186.49.3.153
```

I have been looking around but have had no luck. I have never sent an email from this address, but if I change the credentials and try sending from another account, I have no problem.

I followed the link, and looked up for the ip address in the message error (186.49.3.153). [This](http://www.spamhaus.org/query/ip/186.49.3.153) link leads to the page where it says that the IP is listed on the Policy Block List (PBL). I read the description, saying that if I am using any normal email software (Outlook, Entourage, etc) then it is simply because I need to turn on "SMTP authentication".

However, this is not the case since I am sending emails using .NET. Any ideas of what I should do?

Comment: Looking at the website it says the IP is invalid. But if your spamming people, your IP could be blocked by the mail provider to prevent further spamming.

Comment: I followed the link too, the link is incorrect. I selected the choice "Lookup another address", and looked for 186.49.3.153. [This](http://www.spamhaus.org/query/ip/186.49.3.153) is the correct link. And no, this is not spam. I send emails to the clients of my organization.

Comment: Have you tried removing it from the blacklist? The webpage explains why you are blacklisted. Its also possible if your not on a static IP that you are using an IP that someone else has caused to blacklist.

Comment: I hadn't tried because I thought I had to be the "owner" of this IP address, however _apparently_ I have been able to remove it. It says I should wait around 30 minutes for servers around the world to update. Just to clarify this: that IP address is the one of the mail server, right?

Comment: Yes. Its blocking the IP of the mail server. :) Ill add my answer. So you can accept if I helped ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mail server IP is being blocked (as the website provided will show).

The webpage explains why you are blacklisted.

Its also possible if your not on a static IP that you are using an IP that someone else has caused to blacklist.

For what ever reason you are blocked, there is an option provided to unblocking your IP. Just follow the instructions, and you should be up and running again shortly.

Comment: Good questions, but should really be in comments only. Alternatively, you could rephrase it so that it reads more like a definitive answer. If you can reword, I'll change my downvote to an upvote.

Comment: @BrianWarshaw Noted, and improved.

Comment: Voting status likewise improved :-)